# Determine locale by domain - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, localization

I am pretty new to localization. Having never had to build multilingual site, I have never built something to serve a specific language.

We currently have example.com, example.co.za and example.gr. Our Wordpress site is hosted on example.co.za in English and is served to all 3 domains in English. We want, when a user hits example.gr, to serve a Greek site. But, we only want one Wordpress site that we update and maintain. I understand that we will need to translate our content into the languages we require, but that's not an issue.

Based on the above, I have a few questions.

1. What would be the best solution for this?
2. Is it possible running 1 WP instance and achieving this, and how would I do it?
3. Is there a way that I can change locale by checking which domain was requested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use a translation/multisite plugin like [MultilingualPress Pro](https://marketpress.de/product/multilingual-press-pro), they link several blogs together and help you with translating etc.
2. Use a [multisite install,](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) every language is an own blog (they can be duplicated [with this plugin for example](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-clone-duplicator/)) and can be managed independently, but they all get connected through 1.
3. You could, but 1. for example automatically detects and redirects based on the browser language, which seems to me like a better solution. This works fine for me in a similar environment.

(I am in no way connected to the linked, paid plugin, but I am using it in two sites and am fine with the work it does.)